# class not found cygwin, bad interpreter

Tags: java, perl, class, cygwin, interpreter

I am trying to execute a shell script via cygwin
sh scriptname.sh parameters

-Below are errors.

1. Class not found "com.eeplugins.Testcase"
2. scriptname: line 76 : dos2unix: commant not found
3. scriptname: ../bin/unbundle.pl: /usr/bin/perl: bad interpreter: Permission denied

i've tried setting class path, cygwin home, installed perl but not change in output.

Your inputs/comments will be highly appreciated.

Comment: could you provide the code and how are you setting the classpath

Answer (score 2):

1. ClassNotFound means that your class path is wrong. Check it. Modify your script at line that runs java: add `echo` before. It will print the whole command line instead of running it. Examine command line, check that classpath is defined correctly.
2. `dos2unix` not found means that this command indeed does not exist in your environment. I've just checked mine: it does not exist too. Refer to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/612435/cygwin-dos2unix-command-not-found) discussion to find out how to install it. Alternatively use other shell. For example I use gitshell that has this utility.
3. Because `dos2unix` wasn't able to run, the OS is looking for an interpreter named `/usr/bin/perl\r` (where `\r` represents a Carriage Return) instead of `/usr/bin/perl`, and no such file exists.

Comment: "Class not found" could also mean the class doesn't exist on his system.

Comment: @ikegami, you are right, I just forgot to mention this in my answer.